# how to create a global search functionality in ionic?

Tags: angularjs, search, ionic-framework

i need to create a search bar that should gets displayed on each and every view of my app , when i click the search icon in nav bar that search bar should gets open and a separate page should gets open to search the items globally , how can i do that ? kindly help.

here is my app.js

```
 .state('login', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'login/login.html',
    controller: 'loginCtrl'
  })
   .state('home', {
        url: "/home",
        templateUrl: "home/home.html",
        controller:"homeCtrl"

  })
    .state('assetview', {
        url: "/assetview/:subServiceLineId/:serviceLineName",
        templateUrl: "assetview/assetview.html",
        controller: 'assetlistCtrl'

  })
```

i have put my search bar into index.html so it is visible on every view :

```
<body ng-app="starter">
  <ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear" side="left">
        </ion-nav-back-button>

          <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
            <sos-header></sos-header>
              <button class="ion-ios-search-strong button-clear search-icon" ng-hide="showme" ng-click="searchclick()"></button>

          <div class="" ng-show="showme" style="width: 132%; height: 33px">
                    <div>
                        <label class="">
                              <input type="search" placeholder="Search" style="height: 28px; margin-left: -212px background-color:blue;">
                        </label>
                        <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="showme = false" style="padding-right: 98px;">
                        Cancel
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="showme = false" style="padding-right: 98px;">
                        Cancel
                        </button>
                    </div>
          </div>
          </ion-nav-buttons>  


  </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view>

    </ion-nav-view>

  </body>
```

Comment: What do you want to search? Is the data only local in html files? Is it json from a server? Your question is way to broad!

Comment: its a json from server

Comment: Then you need to provide some search functionality on your server where you send the search keywords with an ajax request (using angulars `$http` library, see here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) and you get back the results. Then you display your results

Comment: what if i want to create a angular filter on the the data coming from server ? as i am storing that data into arrays ?